# VBA Validation in a selected range

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I can't seem to get my validation working properly on the example below. I want to restrict the user so that he/she can't overwrite the numbers with any kind of number or letter which are already in the cells.(for example: if there is a 9 in a cell, and he/she wants to overwrite it to 8, don't let it, just pop an error message and reset it to the original value). I've tried several restrictions both in vba and in excel's data --> validation option and watched numerous videos, but i can't seem to figure it out, thought it must be some trivial command I just don't know it. The catch is, that the values would change constantly in the range, and so i can't just select the cells that do have value in them.

The selected range of this would be B2:J10.

[image]

Comment: One way to do this is to select the cells that CAN be changed, right-click and choose Format Cells. On the protection tab, unchecked "Locked." Then click on the Review tab, and choose Protect sheet, enter a password, and then save the file.

Comment: Yes, the protection already crossed my mind but the values of this range would constantly change, and so once it would work, but other time it wouldn't.

Comment: You're creating these puzzles with VBA, I'm assuming? If you are, can't you use that to lock/unlock certain cells?

Comment: Yes, that is correct I'm using VBA. I was trying to do it like that in the first place, but couldn't find a solution unfortunately. I'll keep looking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired on extensionhelp's questions, I figured out a way to restrict the cells that contain values. Here is the code if anyone is wondering about it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Rng
Dim MyCell

Set Rng = Range("B2:J10")
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If MyCell.Value = "" Then

    Else: ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
    End If
Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, it sounds like Locking/Unlocking the cells with VBA is your best option. Every cell within a sheet is locked by default, but the locking doesn't take effect until you Protect the sheet. As you're generating the puzzle, unlock specific cells with something like:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Locked = False
```

After you've generated the puzzle, protect the sheet with:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SomePassword", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

If, within the macro, you need to unprotect a sheet, you would use:

```
ActiveSheet.UnProtect Password:="YourPassword"
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification of the cell's behaviour in excel, extensionhelp! I used similar technique to solve the problem too, just right before you posted your answer. I appreciate your time and solution for solving this problem with me.